# Access rest api endpoint docker

Tags: php, apache, rest, symfony, docker

I have built simple api endpoint using symfony/fosrest etc. I can access it via symfony build in server ie: `php bin/console server:run`.

Now I want to access api in docker. I have created docker-compose.yml with php-apache and mysql image. Now when I try to connect to the endpoints as follows I get forbidden (403) error. I assume my apache configuration in docker php-apache image is incorrect. Can anyone please help me to fix this. thanks.

```
endpoint: POST http://192.168.99.100/api/myendpoint
```

Error is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /api/myendpoint on this server.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.99.100 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

*EDIT - `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2"
services:
  myapp:
      build: ./docker
      image: php5.6-apache
      container_name: myapp
      ports:
          - "80:80"
      volumes:
          - .:/app
          - $HOME/.composer/cache:/root/.composer/cache
      working_dir: /app
      links:
          - mymysql
      environment:
          - APPLICATION_ENV=test

  mymysql:
      image: mysql:5.6
      container_name: mymysql
      ports:
          - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
          - data:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
          - MYSQL_USER=root
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password

volumes:
  data:
```

**ANSWER**:

run following in your symfony application.

```
docker exec -it your_container_name php bin/console server:run 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And change your docker application ports to `8000:8000` in docker-compose.yml

Now you should be able to access your endpoint as follows.

```
POST http://192.168.99.100/api/myendpoint
```

Your docker IP address can be different to my one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really provide your docker-compose.yml to help diagnose the problem, but I would say this is one or more of the following problems (I know because I've probably done all of them wrong at some point too):

- The command `php bin/console server:run` is failing because it is not being run in the right directory. The logs on `docker-composer up` would show you this and the container would fail to start
- Your server is listening on the default port of 8000 and not accepting connections from outside the loopback address. You can provide an IP and port combo as an argument to server:run to override this. See [Using the built-in Web Server from inside a Virtual Machine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html) in the Symfony docs
- Your port mapping is incorrect in `docker-compose.yml`, it should be using the port you use in the `server:run` command.
- You have apache or another webserver running on the host machine which is producing the page you see

Comment: Added docker-compose.yml. Thanks I have fixed this following your tips. Thanks much.